# Actionscript Take Input and compare to an Int

Tags: string, actionscript-3, int, var

I'm trying to take an input from the user using an Input Text field, this data is a number. I want the user to input the correct number (in this case 1) and then print out yay.

However, i can't get it to work. Any help is much appreciated.

I assume the issue is to do with comparing an int and a string, but honestly im not sure anymore.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

var dayVar:String = dayInput.text;
var dayNum:Number = Number(dayVar);


stop();

button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler3);

function mouseDownHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(dayNum == 1) {
        trace("yay");
    } else {
        trace("nay");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you update `dayVar` in some point after user input? If not, try `if(Number(dayInput.text)==1){` instead of your current if-condition.

Comment: @kaarto Thank you! This was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to update your `dayVal` and/or `dayNum` **after** user has given input. So in this minimal case you can simply:

```
function mouseDownHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if(Number(dayInput.text)==1) {
        trace("yay");
    } else {
        trace("nay");
    }
}
```

Other possibilites would be listening [Event.CHANGE](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextInput.html#event:change) for the text input, or [KeyboardEvent](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html) to update your variables, but in this case the `MouseEvent` handler does the job easier.

Answer (score -1):

You can use restriction property for text field input like this:

```
dayInput.restrict = "0-9";
```

This should omit to type only digits.